# Condition Check in a Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

Cell A1=1, A2=1, A3=A1*A2

When I change A1 Value and if it gives A3>previous value I would like to store the A1=A4

here is explained with Image
Cell A1=1, A2=1, A3=A1*A2

[image]

When I change A1 Value and if it gives A3>previous value I would like to store the A1=A4
[image]

and like this
[image]

another example:

type 68 in A1
type 10 in A2
Now the A3 will be 680 so this is current high value of A3 now the A4 will show 68

and now change to A1 to 67
and A2 to 16 now the value of A3 is 1072 which is higher than previous it was
so the A4 must show now 67 not 68

Comment: What exactly you are trying to solve is difficult for me to understand, edit your question properly !! It's natural since you are inserting higher values like `68` & `10` = `680` which is higher than previous `2` or `3` and if you are trying to compare `680` with `2` or `3` then it need to store in other cell also because new value replaces old one in `A3`, write !!

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement you need a variable to store the cell value "A3". In order to achieve the same you need to do the below details.

- Get the value of A3 and assign it to a variable
- Write a formula in excel in which it compare the value of A3 and variable value and update the A4 with A1 value when ever the A3 value increase from the previously stored value.

For your reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40733786/store-cell-value-in-variable